# How do I perform a dynamic where lambda on T in C# 4?

Tags: c#, linq, func

How can I use a Lambda expression as parameter in this method and use it in the where clause?

Been reading about Func, dynamic and Expression trees but not sure how to do this.

Problem is that I don't know the type T and don't know what the caller want returned.
How can I do this in C# 4.0?
An example to get me started would be great - thanks.

Here is a strongly simplified example of what I want.

```
static public List<T> Match(string startfilelocation, ???)
{
    var filelist = Directory.GetFiles(startfilelocation, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    return filelist.Where(???);
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify `List<string>` as the return type, use the `Func<string, bool>` type for the parameter, then the `ToList` method to turn the result into a list:

```
static public List<string> Match(string startfilelocation, Func<string, bool> filter) {
  var filelist = Directory.GetFiles(startfilelocation, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
  return filelist.Where(filter).ToList();
}
```

Example:

```
List<string> files = Match(folder, s => s.Contains("candy"));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static public IEnumerable<string> Match(string startfilelocation,Func<string,bool> selector) 
{ 
    var filelist = Directory.GetFiles(startfilelocation, ".", SearchOption.AllDirectories); 
    return filelist.Where(selector);
}
```

I also would recommend `Directory.EnumerateFiles` instead of using `GetFiles` not to load all file names to memory

Answer (score 0):

The Where method in LINQ can accept only two parameters `Func<TSource,bool>` and `Func<TSource,int,bool>` . In your case where `filelist` is a `string[]` hence you can have two overloaded methods

```
static public IEnumerable<string> Match(string startfilelocation, Func<string,bool> predicate)
{
    var filelist = Directory.GetFiles(startfilelocation, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    return filelist.Where(predicate);
}



static public IEnumerable<string> Match(string startfilelocation, Func<string,int,bool> predicate)
{
    var filelist = Directory.GetFiles(startfilelocation, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    return filelist.Where(predicate);
}
```